# Visual Studio failing while adding the deployment configuration of the SAPUI5 application

Tags: visual-studio-code, sapui5, sap-fiori

Visual Studio Code is throwing an error while I am trying to add the deployment configuration of the SAPUI5 application. The error message is *"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'www-authenticate') To continue with project generation choose a different deployment target or skip adding deploy config."*

[image]